# How to make sure the footer is always at the bottom?

Tags: 8

As an important note I do NOT mean `position: fixed;`!!!

When the body is smaller and does not take the full height of the browser size, the footer just likes to chill in the middle of the page. If you look in the photo I shared you can see more clearly what I mean. I've tried things like `body{height: 100%;}` to no avail. Even attempted this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ and it seemed to just break it more (especially on the front page where this isn't a problem. Is there possibly a way to make sure the body size is at least the size of the browser always?

[image: example photo]

Comment: This question could also use the markup that is on the page - specifically the containing element and the footer element.

Comment: (not annoyed in any way just trying to understand) I'm a little confused as to why it's off topic? I was asking the question only in the setting of a drupal site, as my previously known solution didn't work with drupal's framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the content gets adjusted as per the content. Hence you can set the height of content-column to screen size in css. But only `#content-column { height: ---px; }` will not work as it will fix your screen to that px only, hence you can solve that issue using `min-height` as shown below. I have set this in my site and it is working perfect

`#content-column { min-height: 500px; }`

So, what happens the content column always remains at around 500px minimum, which is near to average screen size hence, visitor visit your site it looks like filled in entire screen and footer will be always at bottom. and if content is more it will be adjusted accordingly. And you can change px to whatever you want.

**UPDATE-1**

Now with above method, you can set the height which does not go below 500px, but what if the default screen size is more than that. Which had been discussed in following comments,

**You can use the Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax**

So, following code will solve the issue,

`#content-column {min-height: 100vh}`,

where the `1vh = 1% of the screen height`. hence 100vh will cover the entire screen. Now, if you have specified the % in the html {} or body {}, then you need to take that value as 100%.

e.g. 
`body {font-size: 87.5%;}` -> In bartik or Adaptive theme,

so for this your code will be,

`#content-column {min-height: 87.5vh;}`

Comment: The only problem I see with this is what if their browser was significantly big for some reason–say `height: 1000px`. Wouldn't it still look broken?

Comment: That is true, even I thought that thing after posting this answer, tried to post as second option, but had no time. I will try to figure it out and hope will post. Second thing, I do not know what type of your site is, might be you need fit to screen, but it is not a good idea to keep the site page static, I mean it should have some scrolling effect even though you have less content, as visitor comes to any page, by default they like to scroll down, if it is perfectly fit to screen it will not give good effect. Hence, in my site I keep around 800px. this is just my opinion, as I had tried.

Comment: Can you let me know, in your theme css, in html { } or body { } section, what is the % of font-size. It would be like this font-size: ___%; I guess it is not bartik.

Comment: Well the front page certainly has more to scroll through, as do pages like my blog feed, etc. But that could still be a good thing to think about in improving my site.

I only found `font-size: 14px;`

Comment: Ok, there should be other css code in html { } or in body { }, where the font-size should be in %. Which theme are you using?

Comment: if there is no code of font-size: ---%, simply put #content-column { min-height: 100vh !important; }, What this code will do, it will take the browser height 100% and 1vh = 1%. Hence your height will  be always fit to browser. If there is a font-size: ---% in html {} or in body {}, take that value, suppose it is body { font-size: 87.5%} then your code will be #content-column { min-height: 87.5vh !important; }. This should wok as I tries in my site and it is working, even you squeeze the site height manually, it is adjusting, If not working let me know, there is some adjustment needed.

Comment: I did a search for all font-sizes real quick and saw nothing. I'm using Bootstrap's theme, which has no base theme(stark then, correct?). I'll try that out then and get back to you!

Comment: Just add #content-column { min-height: 100vh !important; }, it should work.

Comment: That works perfect from all I can tell!

Comment: Ok, I will update the answer and add this as a second part.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `calc()` expression, and use `min-height` instead of `height`. Say your footer height is 100px:

```
body{
  min-height : 100%;
  min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px); /* Firefox */
  min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px); /* Chrome, Safari */
  min-height: calc(100% - 100px); /* IE9+ browsers */
}
footer{
  height: 100px;
}
```

Get more info about `calc()` [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-calc-function/)

Comment: couldn't find a way to get this to work :/. I think something in drupal was overriding it

Comment: Another trick you should remember is to always put your custom css in a separate css file and include it last after including all other site css. That way you will be sure nothing will override it as it will be rendered last.